# Phonegap Build vs. Phonegap on Xcode4? Config.xml?

Tags: xcode, cordova

Have an application built with phonegap that I've already compiled and tested using the http://build.phonegap.com service.

I'm finding it builds differently with XCode then it did on the Phonegap website.

On phonegap website icons and splash screens found within my config.xml file are found and used.

On XCode the App ends up using the default icon and splash page.

Also my config.xml uses

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Which is needed for my application to work. On the Phonegap website this works but on XCode its not seen and the Application doesn't work.

Does phonegap with XCode not use the config.xml? If not how can I add...

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE AS OF CORDOVA 2.3.0 - February 24th 2013

IOS phonegap/cordova builds using XCode now need a config.xml

See http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/tag/cordova-plist/ for more information

---

OLD ANSWER STILL RELAVENT IF USING ANYTHING UNDER CORDOVA 2.3.0

I'm now 90% sure that the config.xml file is not used. With XCode you can easily select your icons and splash pages with the GUI.

Instead of using...

```
<access origin="*" />
```

in the config.xml file. You look through your file structure for the Cordova.plist. When you click it you'll see several items in the main page. Look for the option called 'ExternalHosts' you'll have to add * as an item there.

Like so...

[image]

Information found at http://samcroft.co.uk/2011/updated-loading-data-in-phonegap-using-jquery-1-5/

Comment: Correct! Phonegap application for iOS doesn't need `config.xml`

Comment: Actually not correct - Phonegap does not, but PhoneGap Build does. PhoneGap Build uses the `config.xml` file to populate the `Cordova.plist` file when it does the compiling.