# phonegap set up for iOS with jquery mobile

Tags: html, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm getting ready to set up a mobile web app I made and make it into a native app for iOS using Adobe's Phonegap Build service. Upon reading their documents on how to set everything up, it mentioned a config.xml file that you use to define icon, splash screen, and title. Seeing as Jquery Mobile does all this through meta tags in the header of an html file, would I still need to use the xml file when using phonegap build?

Comment: I am pretty sure the XML file is used by Xcode as those settings need to exist in Xcode when compiling the ipa. It's been a while since I used PhoneGap though. I would suggest you look into Titanium. It is an opinion, but it's a much more flexible product. And usually produces a much more polished result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>There is no config.xml file in the xcode version of phonegap you use cordova.plist.</s>

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11418415/773263

---

Correction: as of Cordova 2.3.0 cordova.plist is now config.xml

http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/tag/cordova-plist/

So if you are using a version of phonegap under 2.3.0 what I posted above is useful. If using 2.3.0 or above you will need to configure your app via config.xml file.

---

As for if you need to use config.xml or cordova.plist when your using jQuery Mobile the answer is yes, you always have to use config.xml or cordova.plist when using Cordova/Phonegap.

Comment: So its safe to say that once i turn my mobile web app into a native app, I can remove the meta tags that make the web app capable and just rely on JQM for the style and transitions and use the config.xml file for the icon, name, etc.